# Why does Instant File Initialisation make my restore slower

Tags: sql-server, azure-virtual-machine, database-backups

I have a Azure VM with the following:
Windows DataCenter 2019
SQL Server 2017 Developer
Virtual drive of 6TB (built up of 12 512GB Premium SSD disks)
112 GB of RAM
16 VCPUS

I have a db that has a data file of approx ~5TB (2TB empty) and log file of approx ~1TB (99% empty).
I have backed this up to Azure blob storage (64 block blobs).

When I restore to my SQL Server with Instant File Initialisation enabled, it takes ~ 40 hours.
I can see the network and disk Throughput really low.

When I disable Instant File Initialisation, it takes ~3hours to zero out the files and then I get good performance on the restore ~1 1/2 hours (on top of the ~3 hours to zero out the files)

Does anyone know why this could be.

My code to restore

```
restore database [<db_name>] from
url = 'https://.....url_1.bak',
...
url = 'https://.....url_64.bak',
move 'db_log' to 'new log location' -- i am only moving the log file, as the data file's location doesn't change
stats = 1, norecovery;
```

Comment: `Azure VM` means you *don't* have a 6TB drive, you have something that's going to allocate up to 6TB when asked to do so. The Azure VM's *host* doesn't know you need this for SQL Server, so it will delay really allocating any storage until needed. It *won't* allocate any blocks until it actually has to store something in them. Without instant file initialization, the VM asks for 5TB of data *with specific data* right from the start, so the host allocates that storage and returns it.

Comment: *With* instant file initialization, nothing needs to be written so the host won't allocate anything until RESTORE starts writing disk pages. Not when the database files grow, but when the actual blocks have to be written to disk

Comment: Have you checked [Storage configuration for SQL Server VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/storage-configuration)? Although I suspect you already did

Comment: I have followed this with the exception of having the log file and data file on the same drive, can that be the cause?

Comment: That's a *very* big problem, especially since the guide recommends using different caching for the data and log disks. If you had an on-prem server you'd still have a big problem, as data and log writes would compete for the same IO bandwidth. No data is written to a data file before recording the change in the transaction log, so using the same disk for both essentially halves the bandwidth - and adds extra latency.  Using separate data and log files is a standard configuration for any database, not just SQL Server.